# Word that means "almost collide with me"

Tags: single-word-requests

The red guy is looking at the blue guy.

[image]

**Case one:** The red guy violently dashes forward and collides with the blue guy.

[image]

The blue guy says:

> He ***collided*** with me!

**Case two:** The red guy steps forward, and almost collides, but doesn't.

[image]

The blue guy says:

> He **???** with me!

---

The most obvious replacement would be ***almost collided***, but I am looking for a one-word solution. Is there a word that means "almost collide" that would fit in this context?

Comment: I looked up [near miss](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/close%20call) in the thesaurus and these are no one-word results.  Also, even the two word results don't fit your example sentence, i.e. "He close shaved me" doesn't work grammatically.  I doubt there is a one-word answer, but like Bigfoot, you can't prove a negative.

Comment: If there was some contact, you might use *clip*, which (like graze) would indicate that it wasn't actually a collision, just a glancing blow.

Comment: [*Near-missed*](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22near-missed%22&safe=active&tbm=bks&start=190) is used as a verb quite a lot if you check Google Books.

Comment: _Near misses_ (or _avoidances_) happen if red whizzes by blue and continues on.  What OP described is _pulling up short_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The red guy **approached** me." (No contact/motive unclear)

"The red guy **engaged** me." (No contact/menacing implied)

Answer (score 0):

**Graze**

> ɡreɪz/
>
> **verb**
>
> touch or scrape lightly in passing.
> "his hands just grazed hers"
> **synonyms**:   touch, touch lightly, brush, brush against, rub lightly, shave, skim, kiss, caress, sweep, scrape, glance off, clip
> "his shot grazed the far post"

**Near miss**

> **noun**
>
> 1. a narrowly avoided collision or other accident.
>
> "she had a near miss when her horse was nearly sucked into a dyke"
> **synonyms**: close thing, near thing, narrow escape, close call, nasty moment;

Answer (score 0):

You could say *[brush past](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brush+past)*:-

to push quickly past someone or something. *She brushed by the little group of people standing there talking. I brushed by the plant, knocking it over.*

Then your sentence would read "*He brushed past me*".

Comment: I agree that this seems relevant. However, it isn't a single word. (I'm not trying to criticize the post, just to explain why I'm not voting for it even though the meaning seems to fit pretty well.)